# Multiple Expression.Or

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

How to build an expression which will produce the following statement?

```
x => x.Parameter1 == "Some text" || x.Parameter2 == "Some text" || x.Parameter3 == "Some text"
```

It's not hard to do `x =>`, but how to create those many OR operators?

I know we have `Expression.Or` method, but it only accepts 2 arguments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just compile them together

psuedo code:

```
firstOr = Expression.OrElse(x.Parameter2 == "some test", x.Parameter3 == "sometest")

secondOr = Expression.OrElse(firstOr, x.Parameter1 == "Some text");
```

Then all you do is evaluate the `secondOr`

These are [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) , and therefor you compose them together.

when you have multiple elements, segment as you would with a mathematical expression, put parenthesis around parts:

1 + 2 + 5 = 8

this is

(1 + 2) + 5 = 8

So we've turned 1 expression into a composition of 2 expressions.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a piece of code like: `x => (x.Parameter1 == "Some text" || x.Parameter2 == "Some text") || x.Parameter3 == "Some text"`? It's not a big deal, just curious

Comment: Yes it would - but this is what compilers do anyway - order of operations. It's an important thing to consider, and why there are strict rules around it.

Comment: No problem at all

Comment: `Expression.Or` is bitwise operator. You have to use `Expression.OrElse` for boolean operations.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov note if you are combining a lot of `Or`'s this can have a negative consequence see the pitfall for [LINQKit's PredicateBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996364/linqkit-stack-overflow-exception-using-predicate-builder)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yeah so I was saying `psuedo code` because writing out full expression tree stuff is painful. I've update my code snippet to reflect that - but essentially the question is more around the concept rather than actual implementation

Comment: @CallumLinington, `Expression.Or` is known static method and I saw a lot of mistakes when using it. Generated SQL is correct  but awful for performance. Your answer is full of pseudo abstraction but this part can be replicated  by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'd better use the `Expression.OrElse()` method. The method `Expression.Or()` represents a bitwise OR operation, i.e. `x.Parameter1 == "Some text" | x.Parameter2 == "Some text"`

```
var condition1 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "parameter1"),
    Expression.Constant("Some text 1"));
var condition2 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "parameter2"),
    Expression.Constant("Some text 2"));
var condition3 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "parameter3"),
    Expression.Constant("Some text 3"));

var result = Expression.OrElse(condition1, Expression.OrElse(condition2, condition3));
```